# Docker run --volume keeps creating random volumes and not using the one specified

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Docker keeps creating random volumes instead of using the I specify when running `docker run...`.

I'll start out with no volumes.

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
```

I'll create one

```
docker volume create myvol
```

It'll get created

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               myvol
```

I'll start a container using the volume

```
$ docker run -d \
  --name myapp \
  --publish 1337:1337 \
  --volume myvol:/my-work-dir/.tmp \
  foo/bar:tag
```

I'll go and check my volumes again and I have the one I created and a new one.

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               9f7ffe30c24821c8c2cf71b4228a1ec7bc3ad6320c05451e42661a4e3c2c0fb7
local               myvol
```

Why isn't `myvol` being use? Why is a new volume being created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when the image you are using defines a VOLUME in the Dockerfile to a container path that you do not define as a volume in your run command. Docker creates the guid for the volume name when you have a volume without a source, aka an anonymous volume. You can use `docker image inspect` on the image to see the volumes defined in that image. If you inspect the container (`docker container inspect`), you'll see that your volume is being used, it's just that there's a second anonymous volume to a different path also being used.

Comment: This was it. I was using a `VOLUME` within my `Dockerfile` that didn't match the `--volume` I was using for `docker --run`. Deleting the `VOLUME` in the `Dockerfile` and just using the `--volume` flag with `docker run` worked. No more unnamed volumes being created after subsequent `docker run`'s. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## How to work with volumes:

To create a volume:

```
docker volume create my-vol
```

To use this volume:

```
docker run -d  --name devtest -v my-vol:/app   nginx:latest
```

Comment: How is this different than what the OP did?

Comment: OP have edit his Question now. Before he has created his volume by docker volume create --name myvol  and this creates an container with the Name myvol and not a volume with this Name. You can see it in Question history

Comment: The `--name` option works, at least on my current version of docker, it's just not documented in the `--help` output. The `docker volume create` command never creates a container, it creates a volume with that name.

Comment: Sorry, for me always was --name an eye marker to specify the name of the container - for some other people too ;-)  We don't had read the full command carefully