# How to remove docker-volume of (removed) docker-container?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have tests that runs lots of docker containers. each of them has a volume.

**How can I know the volume name that I need to delete?**

for example:

```
~ docker run -d registry:2 
~ docker volume inspect c80fc65a79039d70cf54b3af3ab66b378dec42d0757928ae94277b197d8d8104
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-08-14T11:33:50Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/c80fc65a79039d70cf54b3af3ab66b378dec42d0757928ae94277b197d8d8104/_data",
        "Name": "c80fc65a79039d70cf54b3af3ab66b378dec42d0757928ae94277b197d8d8104",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

After manually stopping and removing the `registry:2` container, the volume still exists.

I don't want to delete all volumes because some of them are still in use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to determine the volume name by yourself. Actually, you have mutliple options here.

#### You can use the `--rm` Flag on `docker run` if you want to clean up

Reference: [docs.docker.com: Clean Up (--rm)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm)

> If you set the --rm flag, Docker also removes the anonymous volumes associated with the container when the container is removed. This is similar to running docker rm -v my-container. Only volumes that are specified without a name are removed. For example, when running:

#### Use the `docker system prune --volumes` command to clean up all volumes not used by at least one container

Reference: [docs.docker.com: docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

> Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.

#### Get the associate volumes

If you really want to get the volumes of a container you can use the snippet

```sh
docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }}{{ printf "\n" }}{{ range .Mounts }}{{ printf "\n\t" }}{{ .Type }} {{ if eq .Type "bind" }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}{{ .Name }} => {{ .Destination }}{{ end }}{{ printf "\n" }}' <continaer-id>
```

Answer (score 4):

To clean all the anonymous volumes I am using this:

```
docker volume ls | awk '{if (length($2)==64 && $2!~/-/ && $2!~/_/) print $2}' | xargs -L1 docker volume rm
```

if you are wondering why those random volumes exists please read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62654594)

Answer (score 1):

You can either delete unused volume manually:

```
docker volume rm c80fc65a79039d70cf54b3af3ab66b378dec42d0757928ae94277b197d8d8104
```

Or [prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/) all unused volumes

```
docker volume prune
```

Remove all unused local volumes. Unused local volumes are those which are not referenced by any containers

Comment: how do I know the volume name that I need to delete? thats what im looking for...

Comment: did you check `prune`?

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer might help anyone:

Remove the volumes associated with the container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973133/4883721.

Comment: That thread only gives the information how to remove ALL volumes for ALL containers on the machine. That's not what OP wanted.